# how do you load an ssh_config file within a cron job

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync

[ssh_config](http://man.cx/ssh_config) files allow you to configure an ssh client

You can specify aliases, default users and identity files for different ssh hosts, amongst other things

The docs state that the ssh_config options are loaded magically by the ssh client in the following order:

1. command line options
2. user-specific file (~/.ssh/config)
3. system-wide file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config)

However, these configuration options aren't automatically available/respected within a cron job context

how can you load an ssh configfile such as ~/.ssh/config for a crontab context or in a specific cronjob?

Update:
issue was this: https://superuser.com/questions/508408/public-key-always-asking-for-password-and-keyphrase

Comment: Why do you think ssh doesn't read those files when it's run from cron?

Comment: yeah, maybe i'm making assumptions here, but executing 'ssh host echo 1' from my shell works but throws Permission denied (publickey) when executed within a cron job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh --help` says that there is a `-F configfile` option.  However, I think `ssh` should still be checking in ~/.ssh/config and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, even when run via `cron`.

When run from `cron`, the `HOME` environment variable is set to point to your normal home directory, so `ssh` has all the information it needs to locate the standard configuration files.

I tested this by putting the following `cron` job in place:

```
* * * * * strace -o /tmp/trace -f -s 80 ssh localhost uptime > /tmp/trace
```

And inspecting `/tmp/trace` after the job has run, I see:

```
29079 open("/home/lars/.ssh/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
29079 open("/etc/ssh/ssh_config", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

**Update**

On my OS X machine (OS X 10.10.3), I set up the following `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host stackoverflow
  Hostname fileserver.house
  IdentityFile fileserver_rsa
```

I created the following cron entry:

```
* * * * * ssh stackoverflow uptime > $HOME/output
```

The only way that would work would be if ssh were reading my `~/.ssh/config` file...and it works just fine.  What leads you do believe that things aren't working?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is really useful. I'm using OSX, and obviously it isn't for me. but it's good to know that it is for you on Linux. I will check with dtrace and also inspect the HOME variable in the same fashion

Comment: Ssh doesn't actually read the HOME environment variable. It generally calls `getpwuid()` to get the user's account information.

Comment: The point was that regardless of how it locates config files it has all the information necessary available in the context of a cron job.

Comment: @Kenster, larsks, I was able to debug this issue by piping stdout from the ssh command in verbose mode, which revealed this was nothing to do with the config not being loaded correctly, but rather because  'key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed'. This is the expected behaviour since my private keys are encrypted and not available to the cron ssh session. Thanks for your help!